# Expresión regular en Scala para parsear un JSON

Tags: json, regex, scala

Quisiera saber qué expresión regular puedo utilizar en [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) sobre la siguiente cadena para quedarme solo con los datos: `"informaciontech"` y `"business"` para el primer caso e `"informationtech"` para el segundo, obviando el resto de la cadena.

```
val str = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech","business"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""

val str2 = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""
```

Tan solo consigo quedarme con lo siguiente para cada caso con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
val pattern = new Regex("""(("[a-zA-Z]*"(,)*{0,1})+)""")

val str = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech","business"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""

val str2 = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""

println((pattern findAllIn str).mkString(","))

println((pattern findAllIn str2).mkString(","))
```

---

Resultado:

```
"data","categories","informationtech","business","url"

"data","categories","informationtech","url"
```

Comment: Yo he usado [esta regex](https://regex101.com/r/dM3oC3/1): `\"categories\"\s*:\[(.+?)(?:,(.+?))?\]`. Pero estàs seguro de que necesitas regex para esto? No te iría mejor un intérprete de Json?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta :-) Nunca he utilizado un intérprete de Json, soy bastante nueva desarrollando en scala, echaré un vistazo. Gracias!

Comment: @Mariano es cierto. Pero ¿qué podemos hacer con especificaciones tan vagas? ó_ò más aún sospechando que lo que el usuario necesita es interpretar Json en lugar de aplicar una RegEx.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster jaja. Sólo preguntarle y esperar la respuesta como hiciste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Interpretando como JSON

Es importante remarcar que, como `str` es un [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), podemos usar una (de las muchas) librerías para interpretarlo, de modo que sea más directo, confiable y recomendable.

#### Código

Usamos

```java
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._
```

Para luego interpretarlo en [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) con [`parseFull()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/util/parsing/json/JSON$.html#parseFull(String):Option[Any]).

```scala
val str = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech","business"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""

class JO[X] { def unapply(js:Any):Option[X] = Some(js.asInstanceOf[X]) }

object M extends JO[Map[String, Any]]
object L extends JO[List[Any]]
object S extends JO[String]

for {
    Some(M(map)) <- List(parseFull(str))
    L(data) = map("data")
    M(item) <- data
    L(categories) = item("categories")
} yield {
    (item, categories)

    val resultado = categories.mkString("\n")
    println(resultado)
}
```

Durante el bucle, las asignaciones van llamando a `unapply()`, definido arriba.

#### Resultado:

```
informationtech
business
```

[<kbd>Demo en codepad</kbd>](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/BewilderedModestGossipPasta)

---

## 2. Capturando con RegEx

Alternativamente, si aún te interesa utilizar una expresión regular, podemos usar la siguiente expresión:

```regex
(?:[{,]\s*"categories"\s*:\s*\[|\G(?!\A)\s*,)\s*"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
```

#### Descripción

- `(?:[{,]\s*"categories"\s*:\s*\[|\G(?!\A)\s*,)` - [Grupo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) con las 2 opciones de cómo puede empezar una coincidencia:

  1. `[{,]\s*"categories"\s*:\s*\[` - El [caracter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `{` o `,` seguido de `"categories":[` (con espacios opcionales antes y después), [o](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)
  2. `\G(?!\A)\s*,` - Continuando [al final de la coincidencia anterior](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) (si ya se encontró un valor), coincidir con una coma `,`
- `\s*"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - seguido de espacios opcionales, comillas `"`, [capturando el contenido](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) y comillas `"` al final.
  Para coincidir con el contenido entre comillas:

  - `[^"\\]*` - Cualquier caracter que no sea `"` ni `\`.
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - o una `\` seguida de cualquier caracter y de nuevo el anterior `[^"\\]*` (todo esto [repetido](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`: cuantas veces pueda coincidir).

#### Código:

Obtenemos los detalles de la coincidencia con [`.matchData`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/util/matching/Regex$$MatchData.html) para luego acceder con `.group(1)` al texto capturado por el primer conunto de paréntesis de la expresión regular.

```scala
val str = """{"data":[{"categories":["informationtech","business"],"url":"webshrinker.com"}]}"""

val pattern = """(?:[{,]\s*"categories"\s*:\s*\[|\G(?!\A)\s*,)\s*"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"""".r
val resultado = pattern.findAllIn(str).matchData

resultado foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

#### Resultado:

```
informationtech
business
```

[<kbd>Demo en codepad</kbd>](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/SingingFaintOhioSmile)

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final utilicé el intérprete de Json y va perfecto :-) Un saludo a todos y gracias de nuevo por compartir vuestros conocimientos, son de mucha ayuda y nos permiten aprender al resto.